# Is DNA of all animals made of the A,T,C,G blocks?

Tags: dna

Is it true that DNA of all animals is made of the A,T,C,G blocks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DNA is not made of these blocks only. But the genetic information is conveyed through the series of these four block.

All animals, all plants, all fungi, all other eukaryotes, all bacteria, all archea and plenty of viruses use these four blocks. Some viruses use RNA instead of DNA, in which case the `T` is replaced by a `U` (Uracile).

You will find more information on [wikipedia > DNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA).